# How to calculate relatedness in haplodiploid organisms (mainly full sisters and full brothers)?

Tags: genetics, altruism

I have tried to calculate the relatedness for haplodiploid organisms, but cannot understand the calculations behind full sister and full brother.

[image: Haplodiploidy r taken from wikipedia]
(taken from [Wikipedia: haplodiploidy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplodiploidy#Relatedness_ratios_in_haplodiploidy)

I have managed to solve the other cases. Since female will have ZZ:

> female will share 1/2 of her genes with daughter
>
> female will share 1/2 of her genes with son
>
> female will share 1/2 of her genes with mother
>
> female will share 1/2 of her genes with father

Since male will have only Z:

> male will share 1 (100%) of his genes with his daughter
>
> male won't share anything with his son (unfertilized eggs leads to male in haplodiploidy system)
>
> male will share 1(100%) of his genes with his mother
>
> male won't share anything with his father (unfertilized eggs leads to male in haplodiploidy system)

Even though I figured out how others work, I wasn't able to calculate r for fullsister fullbrother? How can it be 3/4,1/4,1/2,1/2?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you should sow us the work you've done so far, including the ones you already figured out.

Comment: The table is taken from [Wikipedia: Haplodiploidy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplodiploidy#Relatedness_ratios_in_haplodiploidy), right? If so, you should include a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a relative thing in haplodiploidy system.

> r = Mother's side + father's side(in this case)
>
> D--Daughter
>
> S--Son
>
> F-Father
>
> M-Mother

**Note:**

> You can get the below things from the question image itself.(All that you need to do is to read male and female appropriately as son,father,mother,daughter based on the context.So simple!)
>   [image: question image]
>
> 1.r<sub>MD</sub>=1/2
>
> 2.r<sub>MS</sub>=1/2
>
> 3.r<sub>DM</sub>=1/2
>
> 4.r<sub>DF</sub>=1/2
>
> 5.r<sub>FD</sub>=1
>
> 6.r<sub>FS</sub>=0
>
> 7.r<sub>SM</sub>=1
>
> 8.r<sub>SF</sub>=0
>
> **case 1:**
>
> r<sub>DD</sub>=(r<sub>DM</sub>*r<sub>MD</sub>) + (r<sub>DF</sub>*r<sub>FD</sub>)
>
> r<sub>DD</sub>=(1/2*1/2)+(1/2*1)
>
> r<sub>DD</sub>=**3/4**
>   [image: female full sister]
>   **case 2:**
>
> r<sub>DS</sub>=(r<sub>DM</sub>*r<sub>MS</sub>) + (r<sub>SF</sub>*r<sub>FD</sub>)
>
> r<sub>DS</sub>=(1/2*1/2)+0*1
>
> r<sub>DS</sub>=**1/4**
>   [image: female full brother]
>   **case 3:**
>
> r<sub>SD</sub>=(r<sub>SM</sub>*r<sub>MD</sub>) + (r<sub>DF</sub>*r<sub>FS</sub>)
>
> r<sub>SD</sub>=(1*1/2)+(1/2*0)
>
> r<sub>SD</sub>=**1/2**
>   [image: male full sister]
>   **case 4:**
>
> r<sub>SS</sub>=(r<sub>SM</sub>*r<sub>MS</sub>) + (r<sub>SF</sub>*r<sub>FS</sub>)
>
> r<sub>SS</sub>=(1*1/2)+(0*0)
>
> r<sub>SS</sub>=**1/2**
>   [image: male full brother]

Answer (score 7):

It is useful to think in terms of the proportion of genetic material that an individual gets from each parent and the amount of this genetic material that will be shared with another individual (on average), and then sum this together i.e. as:

$ relatedness = prop_{mother} * shared_{mother} + prop_{father} * shared_{father} $

A female will share 50% of the genetic material from the mother's side and 100% if the material from the father's side with her full sisters: $0.5*0.5 + 0.5*1 = 0.75$

A female will share 50% of the genetic material from the mother's side and 0% if the material from the father's side with her brother: $0.5*0.5 + 0.5*0 = 0.25$

A male will share 50% of the genetic material from the mother's side with his sister (and doesn't get any from the father's side).

A male will share 50% of the genetic material from the mother's side with his brother (and doesn't get any from the father's side).

Remember also that this only holds if the female has only mated once.

Comment: A female will share 50% of the genetic material from the mother's side and 100% if the material from the father's side with her full sisters--then it should be 0.5*0.5+1*1 right? and A female will share 50% of the genetic material from the mother's side and 0% if the material from the father's side with her brother: 0.5∗0.5+0*0 right?

Comment: A female still gets 50% of her genetic material from each parent, so it should be 0.5 in both calculations. The first case you suggest would lead to a relatedness of 1.25, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Yes but are we using 0.5 because 1.25 is impossible?

Comment: No, because 50% (0.5) of the genetic material in a female comes from each parent.

Comment: okay relatedness=propmother∗sharedmother+propfather∗sharedfather Does this generalised statement apply in all cases other than haplodiploidy to calculate relatedness?

Comment: @ecolover In the general case it should hold, but I haven't considered it from all angles. Overall, you should be careful when thinking about/calculating relatedness in species with peculiar chromosomal makeups. The sex determining system is also important part, and there are in fact deviations from the general pattern for certain ancestral pairs (due to the inheritance of X & Y chromosomes). For instance, Paternal grandmothers are more closely related to their granddaughters than grandsons (see [paper](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/early/2009/10/27/rspb.2009.1660.full)).

Comment: @fileunderwater I'm sorry for not informing you earlier but I've quoted your answer in a different [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128578/understanding-probability-through-coeffient-of-relatedness) without your consent. After being pointed out by a senior user of that site, I realised I should have done this before. If you don't approve of this I'll flag it for closure.

Comment: @Tytoalba Forgot to answer this. No worries. That is ok.