# What is the coefficient of relatedness between a queen bee and her daughter if the male that mated with the queen was the queen’s own son?

Tags: genetics, population-genetics

What is the coefficient of relatedness between a queen bee and her daughter if the male that mated with the queen was the queen’s own son?

The answer should be 0.75, but I keep getting 1 because 0.5(queen-daughter) + 0.5(queen-male) * 1(male-daughter) = 1.

1 also makes sense because all of the daughter's genes come from the queen. However, I do understand that there is a chance that the genes inherited from the daughter's mother and father may overlap. How is that calculated?

Comment: When dealing with haplodiploidy (male are haploids and females are diploid as it is the case in bees), there are several ways at looking coefficient of relationship and the coefficient of relationship between `A` and `B` may differ from the coefficient of relationship between `B` and `A`. Considering (male-daughter) as being 1 is the source of your issues

Comment: I misread it as Rotatedness, and I thought that scientists had figured out that bees signal to each other at N degrees between queen bee and her daughter if the male that mated with the queen was the queen’s own son. that was funny.

Comment: Remi, I understand what you’re saying and also that bees are haplodiploids. I thought that when tracing from Queen—>male—>daughter, I’d consider them in the same order that they appear. So regarding queen-male, queen has 1 of male’s genome. Regarding male-daughter, the male has 1/2 of daughter’s genome, on average.

Comment: See the answer to this question: [How to calculate relatedness in haplodiploid organisms (mainly full sisters and full brothers)?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21628/how-to-calculate-relatedness-in-haplodiploid-organisms-mainly-full-sisters-and/21638#21638)